# Error in the output of open weather app in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Helo everyone, I have a problem with angular js , I'm developing a small app for weather, and I am using open weather map , but i have error when i launch my app

**here's the result of the app when launching**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOXBa.png)

[image]

**here's my code**

```
// SERVIRES
weatherApp.service('cityService', function() {

    this.city = "New York, NY";

});

// CONTROLLERS

weatherApp.controller('forecastController', ['$scope', '$resource', 'cityService', function($scope, $resource, cityService) {

    $scope.city = cityService.city;

    $scope.weatherAPI = $resource("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=London,us&mode=xml&appid=c4b636e853d2b065e2da4c55eb26e662", { callback: "JSON_CALLBACK" }, { get: { method: "JSONP" }});

    $scope.weatherResult = $scope.weatherAPI.get({ q : $scope.city });

    $scope.convertToFahrenheit = function(degK) {

        return Math.round((1.8 * (degK - 273)) + 32);

    };

    $scope.convertToDate = function(dt) {

      return new Date(dt * 1000);  

    };

}]);
```

Comment: You should have specified which error if it is in console or somewhere else.

Comment: the result of temperature is NaN not showing me the result ..

Comment: inside `$scope.convertToFahrenheit` function add this instead : `return Math.round(degK * 1.8 + 32)`

Comment: No, didn't work :(

Comment: Please create a working demo. I will edit it for you.